# Bartender Print starting position

Tags: bartender

we use a bartender integration to print labels from a Web Application. Now we need the posibility to select the starting postition because we switch to a A4 Sized Page with 48 Labels on it.
Is it possible to send the starting position with a variable on the Get request?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you are using, as you did not mention it. But you should be able to go to File > Page Setup. Click Next 8 times should put you on the "Printing Order" section. Make sure the "Select starting position at print-time" check-box is marked. When you print, you should get a dialog box that will prompt for start position. It will default at position 1 until you marked "Continue from last position of previous job", which will then default to the position of the last label from the last print job this template